# Creating a loading animation between pages on page redirect. VB.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to create a loading icon which triggers on a code behind function (Button click) the function redirects to another page. I am trying to find a way of having a loading icon appear on the button click and go away when the second page is loaded.

I have tried using Jquery by hiding the loading icon on page ready using the following function

```
$('#LoadingIcon').hide()
```

... in the document ready function.

However the icon doesn't appear until the page is already halfway through its loading process.

Any guidance on how I could solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following link which may help you to do this. There's a way to do it using a bit of JavaScript.

http://blog.ysatech.com/post/2010/02/06/ASPNET-redirect-a-web-page-with-AJAX-loading-indicator-image